# Dataframe to CSV returns one empty column which is visible in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

After scraping I have put the information in a dataframe and want to export it to a .csv but one of the three columns returns empty in the .csv file ("Content"). This is weird since the all of the three columns are visible in the dataframe, see screenshot.

[Screenshot dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgLaw.png)

Line I use to convert:

```
df.to_csv('filedestination.csv')
```

Inspecting the df returns objects:

[Inspecting dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9Rnr.png)

Does anyone know how it is possible that the last column, "Content" does not show any data in the .csv file?

[Screenshot .csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ms0Cr.png)

After suggestions it seems that the data is available when opening with .txt. How is it possible that excel does not show the data properly?

[Screenshot .txt file data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdlGf.png)

Comment: try `df['Content'] = df['Content'].astype('str')` . I think it might have to do something with type of column

Comment: Maybe check the raw content of the csv, eg by opening in a text editor, to make sure there is really nothing there and its not just being displayed incorrectly by the program

Comment: Please show the content of the csv file **as text**. Excel is known to process poorly csv files depending on the delimiter, quoting, etc.

Comment: Thanks @ serge ballesta. Opening the file in .txt shows the full data including the column data. How is this possible?

Comment: @raghava Dhanya: i have tried to convert to a string but unfortunately still shows empty cells in excel

Answer (score 0):

What is the data type of the Content column?
It is not a string, you can convert that to a string. And then perform df.to_csv

Comment: unfortunately still shows empt cells in excel after converting to string

Comment: what is the data type of content originally?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, this happens weirdly. View & export will be different. Try Resetting the index before exporting it to .csv/ excel. This always works for me.

```
df.reset_index()
```

then,

```
df.to_csv(r'file location/filename.csv')
```

Comment: Have tried your suggestion but it does not work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

When you click inside the excel cells and see data then it is because of leading spaces. Try removing the leading spaces and it may work.
It did work for me.